# Send from one HTML page to another with two different js

Tags: javascript, html, session, button, interaction

I'm working with HTML and JS on a homepage to send a variable to another js page.

I did this 
in page index i create button with index.js

```html
<a href="index.html" id= "button1">Easy</a>
```

in index .js I did this

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
    sessionStorage.setItem("mood", '1');
    window.location.replace("second.html");
};
```

In second.js I did this in js to take a mood variable.

```js
data = sessionStorage.getItem('mood');
```

Everything works on Firefox (on local), but when using Chrome o online upload the button doesn't work, because it doesn't redirect to second.html

Anyone can help me?
p.s I don't want to use a script (Ajax, Jquery, etc..)

Comment: is button1 meant to be going to second.html or index.html?

Comment: button1 call index.html that have index.js that replace to second.html

Comment: But your button1 href = "index.html" but on the onclick you want it to go to "second.html"?

Comment: yes with the variable. But i cant to do "href =second.html" because dont call the index.js onclick method and dont set the variable mood @Jaxi

Comment: Set the href to '#', or better yet switch it from an `a` tag to a `button` tag. then it will run the onclick function, set your storage then redirect to second.html from index.html.

Comment: Cool. I'll write up a quick answer so something can be accepted, otherwise the question will be left as "unanswered"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in my comment, setting the href to '#', or switching it from an a tag to a button tag will prevent a double page direct, and instead it will run the onclick function, set your storage then redirect to second.html from index.html.

Example:

`<a href="#" id="button1">Easy</a>`

or `<button id="button1" onclick="loadB1()" >Easy</button>`

and call in index.js a function in this way:

```
function loadB1(){
sessionStorage.setItem("mood", '1');
window.location.replace("second.html");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common practice, but you can use browserify
https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify
or requirejs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/requirejs
and make your way "Nodish" style.

EDIT: 
i think it'll work your way if you'll just reference your other file directly.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
document.getElementById("button1").onclick = function(){
sessionStorage.setItem("mood", '1');
 window.location = "http://yourURL.yourURL.com/ourPath/second.html"; 
};
```

Comment: Can I do without external script?I just wish pass a simple variable , seem too much use other js tool

Comment: No dear, dont working i used the solution of @Jaxi and works!